# Update database when IPN payment is made

Tags: php, mysql, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to figure out how to update a a column in my table called Premium_Access when a payment has gone thru with Paypal.

What i have figured out myself is how to update Premium_Access with typing in a specific memberID myself. Like you can see down below in my code.
How and where should i get  the memberID for the logged in user?

Here is my listener.php

```
 header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');

//
// STEP 2 - create the response we need to send back to PayPal for them to confirm that it's legit
//

$resp = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $parm => $var) 
    {
    $var = urlencode(stripslashes($var));
    $resp .= "&$parm=$var";
    }

// STEP 3 - Extract the data PayPal IPN has sent us, into local variables 

  $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
  $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
  $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
  $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
  $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
  $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
  $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
  $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];
  $record_id        = $_POST['custom'];


// Right.. we've pre-pended "cmd=_notify-validate" to the same data that PayPal sent us (I've just shown some of the data PayPal gives us. A complete list
// is on their developer site.  Now we need to send it back to PayPal via HTTP.  To do that, we create a file with the right HTTP headers followed by 
// the data block we just createdand then send the whole bally lot back to PayPal using fsockopen


// STEP 4 - Get the HTTP header into a variable and send back the data we received so that PayPal can confirm it's genuine

$httphead = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.0\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
$httphead .= "Content-Length: " . strlen($resp) . "\r\n\r\n";

 // Now create a ="file handle" for writing to a URL to paypal.com on Port 443 (the IPN port)

$errno ='';
$errstr='';

$fh = fsockopen ('ssl://www.paypal.com', 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);

// STEP 5 - Nearly done.  Now send the data back to PayPal so it can tell us if the IPN notification was genuine

 if (!$fh) {

// Uh oh. This means that we have not been able to get thru to the PayPal server.  It's an HTTP failure
//
// You need to handle this here according to your preferred business logic.  An email, a log message, a trip to the pub..
           } 

// Connection opened, so spit back the response and get PayPal's view whether it was an authentic notification         

else    {
           fputs ($fh, $httphead . $resp);
           while (!feof($fh))
                {
                $readresp = fgets ($fh, 1024);
                if (strcmp ($readresp, "VERIFIED") == 0) 
                    {



$servername = "my db ip";
$username = "my db username";
$password = "my db password";
$dbname = "my database";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


//When the payment is made i want to update Premiumaccsess in members to YES (for the logged in user)
//Im not sure if i should find out who is logged in by memberID or username
$sql = "UPDATE members SET Premium_Accsess='YES' WHERE memberID=15";



if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record updated successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error updating record: " . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();




}

                else if (strcmp ($readresp, "INVALID") == 0) 
                    {

//              Man alive!  A hacking attempt?

                    }
                }
fclose ($fh);
        }


?>
```

And here is my user.php (I dont think i have to do anything more here but if you can see something wrong please tell.)

```
  <?php
include('password.php');
class User extends Password{

    private $_db;

    function __construct($db){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->_db = $db;
    }

    private function get_user_hash($username){

        try {
            $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('SELECT password, username, memberID, Premium_Accsess FROM members WHERE username = :username AND active="Yes" ');
            $stmt->execute(array('username' => $username));

            return $stmt->fetch();

        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo '<p class="bg-danger">'.$e->getMessage().'</p>';
        }
    }

    public function isValidUsername($username){
        if (strlen($username) < 3) return false;
        if (strlen($username) > 17) return false;
        if (!ctype_alnum($username)) return false;
        return true;
    }

    public function login($username,$password){
        if (!$this->isValidUsername($username)) return false;
        if (strlen($password) < 3) return false;

        $row = $this->get_user_hash($username);

        if($this->password_verify($password,$row['password']) == 1){

            $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            $_SESSION['memberID'] = $row['memberID'];
            return true;
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        session_destroy();
    }

    public function is_logged_in(){
        if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && $_SESSION['loggedin'] == true){
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: You listener knows '$payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];'   you could use that in your qeury `$sql = "UPDATE members SET Premium_Accsess='YES' WHERE memberID=15";`  change that to `$sql = "UPDATE members SET Premium_Accsess='YES" WHERE [email_column] = $payer_email` (offcource you need to do this safe)

Comment: So payer_email is the same as the email they have on their account on my website or is it the email on their paypal account? '@RaymondNijland